# In App Purchase ProductID is nil when I get it a second time

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

When I am doing first time non-consumable In-App purchase it's working fine but when I navigate to another screen and try to do In-App purchase my `product_identifier` is `nil`.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: can you show some code..

Comment: Hello abdul now its working fine with my testing bundle identifier . But when am using my app identifier am not getting products from iTunes, we have to set any settings in iTunes.

Comment: Check products available or not else fetch from itunes